# Having issue with jrecorder

Tags: javascript, jrecorder

I'm working with jRecorder its throwing TypeError, getFlashMovie(...).jSendFileToServer is not a function,

```
$.jRecorder(
    {
        host: 'http://website.com/upload/', 
        callback_started_recording: function(){callback_started(); },
        callback_stopped_recording: function(){callback_stopped(); },
        callback_activityLevel: function(level){callback_activityLevel(level); },
        callback_activityTime: function(time){callback_activityTime(time); },
        callback_finished_sending: function(time){callback_finished_sending(rnd); },
        swf_path : 'swf_path/jRecorder.swf',
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved, What I was doing wrong was z-index of #flasharea, I played with id flasharea which contains the adobe flash setting popup.